# $f(x)\ge 0 \implies \lim_{x\to p^{+}}f(x) \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that exists an $r>0$ such that:

$$f(x)\ge0, \forall x\in(p, p+r).$$

I need to prove that:

$$ \lim_{x\to p^{+}}f(x) \ge 0 \tag{when the limit exists}$$

### My attempt:

If the limit exists, then:

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta(\epsilon,p)|0<x-p<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon \implies -\epsilon + L< f(x) < \epsilon + L $$

I just need to prove that $L>0$ because $L$ is the limit. We know that $f(x)\ge0$, then:

$$0\le f(x)<\epsilon + L$$

So we have that

$$\epsilon + L > 0$$

Is this correct? Can I just assume that $\epsilon$ can get small and small such that we can conclude $L>0$?

Comment: You should't necessarily have $L>0$: for example, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$.

Comment: @grantfgates so it should be $L\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @grantfgates but I can't say that $f(x)\le \epsilon + L$ so I can't say that $0\le \epsilon + L$

Comment: $L+ \epsilon > 0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ only implies that $L \ge 0$, not $L > 0$.  For example, $0 + \epsilon > 0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, but $0$ is not greater than $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof:

Suppose $L < 0$, then choose $\epsilon = -L > 0$, thus if $0 < x - p < \delta$ then:

$|f(x) - L| < -L \to L < f(x) - L < -L \to f(x) < L - L = 0$, contradiction. So: $L \geq 0$

Comment: Nice, thanks. Also, do you think my proof is valid?

Comment: @MarterJs: your proof is not valid.

Comment: why? thank you so much :(